# Using conditional return type depending on boolean parameter

Tags: typescript

I am writing a library and I'd like to provide more accurate Types, so that library users can't choose the wrong type in my below example.

This method either returns `IPlayerStats` or `IStatsItem[]` if the parameter `convertJSONOutput` is set to true.

```
public async getStatsById(
    userId: string,
    timeWindow: TimeWindow = TimeWindow.Alltime,
    convertJSONOutput: boolean = true
  ): Promise<IPlayerStats | IStatsItem[]> {
  // Ommitted
}
```

**The question:**

Can I specify a conditional return type which indicates what interface will be returned (depending on the `convertJSONOutput` boolean parameter)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to return different types based on a boolean argument would be overloads:

```
function getStatsById(userId: string, timeWindow: TimeWindow, convertJSONOutput: true): Promise<IPlayerStats>;
function getStatsById(userId: string, timeWindow: TimeWindow, convertJSONOutput: false): Promise<IStatsItem[]>;
function getStatsById(
    userId: string,
    timeWindow: TimeWindow = TimeWindow.Alltime,
    convertJSONOutput: boolean = true
  ): Promise<IPlayerStats | IStatsItem[]> {
```

When you call it, the narrowed type is then inferred based on the value of the argument:

```
// Promise<IPlayerStats>
const a = getStatsById('', undefined, true);

// Promise<IStatsItem[]>
const b = getStatsById('', undefined, false);
```

The important part is that each overload specifies the exact literal value `true` or `false`, rather than the type `boolean`. The return type is then tied to this. I've highlighted the relationship below.

```
//                              **** =>        ************
getStatsById(convertJSONOutput: true): Promise<IPlayerStats>;
```

I have slightly adapted the code so I could create a stand-alone example, it assumes `TimeWindow`, `IStatsItem`, and `IPlayerStats` are already defined:

```
function getStatsById(userId: string, timeWindow: TimeWindow, convertJSONOutput: true): Promise<IPlayerStats>;
function getStatsById(userId: string, timeWindow: TimeWindow, convertJSONOutput: false): Promise<IStatsItem[]>;
function getStatsById(
    userId: string,
    timeWindow: TimeWindow = TimeWindow.Alltime,
    convertJSONOutput: boolean = true
  ): Promise<IPlayerStats | IStatsItem[]> {
  // Ommitted
}

// Promise<IPlayerStats>
const a = getStatsById('', undefined, true);

// Promise<IStatsItem[]>
const b = getStatsById('', undefined, false);
```

Comment: Interesting! I tried it but I get a TS error on the TimeWindow parameter in the first two function overloads now which says `[ts] A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.` I assume I just have to ommit the default value there right?

Comment: Yes - you only need the defaults on the _implementation signature_ not on the overload signatures. You _can_ make parameters optional on the overloads. Imagine the overloads being removed once the compiler has used them to extract type information (because they are!) - so you can't have actual logic in them.

Comment: Unfortunately the default param value doesn't work: `getStatsById('', null) // "Expected 3 arguments, but got 2"`

Comment: And sadly passing a function variable doesn't work either: `function fn(convertJSONOutput: boolean = true) {
  return getStatsById('', null, convertJSONOutput);
} // Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'false'.`

Comment: @Stiggler there has been a subtle change to the transpiled output, so it has to be `undefined` not `null`. I'll udpate.